# Are these sets of complex numbers equal?

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Consider the following sets;

\begin{align}
&S = \left\{ {z \in \Bbb C: 1 \leq \lvert z\rvert\leq 8, \frac{3\pi}{4} \leq \lvert \arg(z)\rvert \leq \frac{3\pi}{2} }\right\}\\
&T = \left \{ { z \in \Bbb C: 1 \leq \lvert z\rvert\leq 8, \frac{11\pi}{4} \leq \lvert \arg(z)\rvert \leq \frac{7\pi}{2}}\right\}
\end{align}

In $T$, the bounds on the argument are simply $\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2\pi$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2} + 4\pi$. Are they equal sets or does this exclude $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$?

**Edit:** The second bound should be $\frac{7\pi}{2}$. That said, the bounds are now $\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2\pi$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2} + 2\pi$ respectively. Are the sets now equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** double check the second bound in $T$, is it $\frac{3\pi}{2} + 2\pi$?

In $T$ there appears to be some complex numbers whose argument is $2\pi$, i.e. on the positive real axis, are there such numbers in $S$?

edit: In response to your edit, so that we have $\frac{3\pi}{2} + 4\pi$, is the interval of the same size as the previous set? As I mentioned, check to see if you can find members in one set that aren't in the other

So as an example using the notation of your sets, $1\notin S$ since $\vert\text{arg}(z)\vert \neq 0 \pm 2n\pi,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ in the range given
but $1 \in T$ with $\text{arg}(z) = 2\pi$ so they are not equal

final edit: with your last edit then yes, the interval is identical as both endpoints differ by $+2\pi$

Comment: Thanks I've just edited my question; does your question still stand taking into account this edit?

Comment: Hahaha, thank you. We got there in the end. I managed to screw up addition, which I think is the source of most of my problems. Thanks a lot for your perseverance.

Comment: Not a problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

After the edit, no they are different. One example of an element in the later but not in the former is $$z = 3e^{\frac{3.5}{2}\pi}=3e^{\frac{9.75}{2}\pi}$$

Comment: @Ed_4434 I have edited this to take into account your edit.

Comment: Thanks, in the end my issue stemmed from a lack of ability to add numbers.